# Express Routing "/"

Tags: node.js, express, routes

In express, when defining my index route, I use "/" (which works), however, I'm trying to make the root configurable, so I tried the following:

```
var root = ""; // can be whatever, but is sometimes empty
app.get(path.join(root, ""), ...);
```

When I start the server (and navigate to the 'index'), I get an error; "`Cannot GET /`", but isn't that what "/" is? How are they different?

Why does `"/"` work when `path.join("", "")` does not work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`path.join("", "")` returns `.`. So it's equivalent to doing `app.get('.', ...);` which won't match requests for `/`.

You could add a check so that root always starts with a leading forward slash:

```
var root = ""; // can be whatever, but is sometimes empty
if (root[0] !== '/')
  root = '/' + root;
app.get(path.join(root, ""), ...);
```

One thing that should be noted is that currently `path.join()` will use the platform-specific path delimiter behavior. So if you're on Windows, `/` will get converted to `\`. For example, `path.join('/', '')` will return `\` on Windows. Although node v0.12 will have the ability to access platform-specific path methods in a cross-platform way (e.g. you can access *nix path functions on Windows).